# sysv init scripts -- differentiate between first run (boot) and subsequent runs

Tags: init.d, startup-scripts, sysv

Normally sysv init scripts are run at boot time (from /etc/init.d/rcS) with the 'start' argument. However they can also be invoked with the 'start' after boot, for exmaple when a service is stopped and then manually restarted.

Is there a "standard", generic way for an init script to differentiate between the first run (at boot) and subsequent runs? (other than manual solutions such as creating a file on the first run and checking for it on subsequent runs)

Comment: I would be interested why you would differentiate these states?

Comment: The script needs to do some startup checks that should only be done once, at boot time, but not once the system is running.

Comment: You could check the current runlevel

Comment: I'm using busybox init -- no runlevels..